# How to free a tree structure in C with a double pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, malloc, valgrind

I'm doing a code about the construction of a tree structure in C, which is not binary. The structure contains a horizontal, a vertical link and a char value. Now i'm trying to free every structure allocated to construct this tree but valgrind gives me an error. I am using a double pointer to point the head of the tree. In the function pile means stack so I stack every node vertically and then I search for the horizontal ones. I'm putting as a picture an example of a tree and its structure and the valgrind result. Can you please help me to understand what is wrong because I don't get it ? Thank you !

```
void libererArbre(cellule ** tete)
{
    cellule * cour = * tete;
    cellule ** temp = &cour; 
    pile_t * pile;
    pile = initialisationPile(TAILLE_PILE);
    int fin = 0;    
    while(fin == 0)
    {   
        while(cour != NULL)
        {
            empiler(cour, pile);
            //printf("empilimi %c\n", cour->valeur);
            cour = cour->lienVertical;
        }
        if(!estVidePile(pile))
        {
            cour = depiler(pile);
            //printf("depilimi %c\n", cour->valeur);
            temp = &cour;
            free(temp);
            cour = cour->lienHorizontal;    
        }
        else
        {
            fin = 1;
            printf("a futet ne fin 1 apo jo \n");
        }
    }
    libererPile(pile);
}
```

Here's a picture of the result of valgrind:

[image]

Here's a picture of the explination of the structure:

[image]

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you without seeing the code that creates the tree.   You appear to have a pointer to a  variable on the stack, rather than an allocated variable.  This might be the root of the tree — or it might be another node.  If I had to guess, it's likely that you didn't allocate the root node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these two lines:

```
        temp = &cour;
        free(temp);
```

Since `cour` is a local variable, `temp` will point to that stack address.  When you call `free(temp)`, you're trying to free a memory address that was not allocated with `malloc`.

You likely need to do something like

```
        temp2 = cour;
        cour = cour->lienHorizontal;    
        free(temp);
```

(where `temp2` is declared as `cellule *temp2`) but it is impossible to know without seeing your allocation code.